# How to add sidebar overlay in leaflet js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, sidebar

I need to add an interactive sidebar to my map.

Im using this as an example to add the sidebar: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp

Ive tried using the sidebar codes provided but it doesnt seem to add anything to the map. I need a sidebar overlay which is the same height and width as the map. Is there any way possible that a sidebar can be added?
If anyone has a solution do let me know or you can write the code down as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
                position: absolute;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
            }
        </style>
        <title>Map Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Leaflet JS</h2>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the example from you, you have to add in the css a high z-index (over 1000), else it is showing below the map and you don't see the sidebar.

I use this sidebar, look into it: https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2

Comment: apologies as Im really inexperienced but do I just copy the code directly from leaflet-sidebar.js and leaflet-sidebar.css ? Both are files of the github link.

Comment: Yes and then you can add the sidebar with: `var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar').addTo(map);`

Comment: I looked at this, and visually ts is impressive. Just a pity that there appears to be no documentation. Read the code, I guess. I will keep looking